# How to show value after submit button in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I made a form in Angular where, **when user submit a form** - **new value show be shown under the form**, I tried everything as per my knowledge but  nothing works, currently labels of below form is showing without click, I need to show everything once where clicked submit button!

My interface: [image]

**HTML FILE**

```
     <div class="form-field col-lg-12">
   <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="click" (click)="update">
              </div>

<div class="form-field col-lg-12">
   <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="click" (click)="update">
</div>
<div *ngIf="display">
   <section class="admin-form">
      <form class="contact-form row">
         <div class="form-field col-lg-6" >
            <label class="label" for="name">Article ID</label>
            <label class="label infolabel" for="name">Fc409702-683e-11eb-Bc5e-54ee750463ec</label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-field col-lg-6 ">
            <label class="label" for="company">Title</label>
            <label class="label infolabel" for="company">SKF India Logs Nearly 2-Fold Rise In Q3 Net Profit</label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-field col-lg-6">
            <label class="label" for="message">Publication, Edition</label>
            <label class="label infolabel" for="message">Times Of India, Mumbai</label>
         </div>
       
            <input class="submit-btn" type="button" value="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popup1">
         </div>
      </form>
   </section>
</div>
```

**TS FIle**

```
    export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  display = true;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
  });
  }
  update(){
    this.display = !this.display;
 }
}
```

Comment: please add your ts file as well.

Comment: In general, in "submit" you call to a service that "update/create" the register. You sould that the service call to the API, and the API return an object. So, in submit, subscribe to the service and **inside** subscription you received the response and show the result

Comment: I have updated TS File too

Answer (score 0):

On `(click)` you call `update` which I'm guessing is a function in your .ts.

If so, your .ts file can have something like this:

```
display: boolean = false;

/*...*/

update() {
  ...
  this.display = true;
  ...
}
```

Then you `*ngIf=display` will trigger and show whatever is contained within

Comment: it hides my div and not showing on click bro

Comment: (click)="update()" instead of (click)="update" fixes it

Answer (score 0):

In the `click` handler, `update` should have `()`, like so:

```
<div class="form-field col-lg-12">
   <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="click" (click)="update()">
</div>

<div class="form-field col-lg-12">
   <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="click" (click)="update()">
</div>
```